# How to store Only one object from response in NSMutableArray in swift 3.0 xcode 8.2 beta?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

```
var arrayData:NSMutableArray = []
if let arrayData = response.result.value{
    print("JSON: \(arrayData)")
}
```

I have response like below:

```
JSON: {
Data =     (
            {
        "Title" = "xyz";
        "Value" = 10;
    },
            {
        "Title" = "abc";
        "Value" = 20;
    }
);
Success = True;}
```

This code store whole response in Array instead of that I want to store only array of Data object in my `arrayData` instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arrayData` instance you have used with `if let` is not your class instance property `arrayData` of type `NSMutableArray`, it remains to that block also it is not array it is dictionary if you want only array of data you need to write like.

```
if let dic = response.result.value as? [String: Any], let array = dic["data"] as? NSArray {
     self.arrayData = NSMutableArray(array: array)
}
```

In Swift it is batter if you use Swift's native `Array` and `Dictionary` instead of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`, So if you want to use native Array then declare your `arrayData` as `[[String:Any]]` means Array of `Dictionary` instead of `NSMutableArray` and use it like this.

```
var arrayData = [[String:Any]]()

if let dic = response.result.value as? [String: Any], let array = dic["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
     self.arrayData = array
}
```